# slicing a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, matplotlib

The following code:

```
import numpy as p
myarr=[[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6],[0,1],[0,6]]
copy=p.array(myarr)
p.mean(copy)[:,1]
```

Is generating the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    p.mean(copy)[:,1]
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index
```

I looked up the syntax [at this link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) and I seem to be using the correct syntax to slice.  However, when I type

```
copy[:,1]
```

into the Python shell, it gives me the following output, which is clearly wrong, and is probably what is throwing the error:

```
array([1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6])
```

Can anyone show me how to fix my code so that I can extract the second column and then take the mean of the second column as intended in the original code above?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your solutions.  However, my posting was an oversimplification of my real problem.  I used your solutions in my real code, and got a new error.  Here is my real code with one of your solutions that I tried:

```
    filteredSignalArray=p.array(filteredSignalArray)

    logical=p.logical_and(EndTime-10.0<=matchingTimeArray,matchingTimeArray<=EndTime)
    finalStageTime=matchingTimeArray.compress(logical)
    finalStageFiltered=filteredSignalArray.compress(logical)

    for j in range(len(finalStageTime)):
        if j == 0:
            outputArray=[[finalStageTime[j],finalStageFiltered[j]]]
        else:
            outputArray+=[[finalStageTime[j],finalStageFiltered[j]]]

    print 'outputArray[:,1].mean() is:  ',outputArray[:,1].mean()
```

And here is the error message that is now being generated by the new code:

```
File "mypath\myscript.py", line 1545, in WriteToOutput10SecondsBeforeTimeMarker
    print 'outputArray[:,1].mean() is:  ',outputArray[:,1].mean()
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

**Second EDIT:**

This is solved now that I added:

```
    outputArray=p.array(outputArray)
```

above my code.

I have been at this too many hours and need to take a break for a while if I am making these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: `outputArray` is a list, not a numpy array. The notation `[:,1]` is numpy specific, not Python general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `p.mean(copy[:,1])` with the indexing before the `mean()` function call. I don't see the problem with the contents of `copy` - it looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you.  But your solution just unearthed a deeper problem in my actual code, which I have now included above.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = numpy.array(myarr)
x[:,1].mean()
```

or

```
numpy.array(myarr)[:,1].mean()
```

or if you really hate yourself,

```
numpy.array(myarr).mean(axis=0)[1]
```

or

```
float(sum(a[1] for a in myarr))/len(myarr)
```

Comment: Thank you.  But your solution just unearthed a deeper problem in my actual code, which I have now included above.